# Aggregate initialization of possibly trivially constructible type. Possible with hidden base class?

Tags: c++, std-pair, aggregate-initialization

I'm trying to implement something like a compressed pair, and would like it to be trivially constructible. I tried to do it in the following way:

```
template<size_t N, typename T, bool inherit = std::is_class_v<T>>
struct PairElement;
template<size_t N, typename T>
struct PairElement<N, T, true> : public T{};
template<size_t N, typename T>
struct PairElement<N, T, false>{ T _hidden_value; };

template<typename A, typename B>
class Pair 
    : public PairElement<0, A>
    , public PairElement<1, B>
{
public:

    constexpr const A& first() const noexcept
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_class_v<A>)
            return static_cast<const A&>(*this);
        else
            return PairElement<0, A>::_hidden_value;
    }
};


Pair<float, int> pair { 0.5f, 10 };
```

In places where just the performance counts this does in fact benchmark better than std::pair in certain situations where the trivial constructability or the empty base class optimization can be used. However a big problem with this implementation is that it can only be aggregate initialized if the pair element base types are inheritted publically, which is anoying because than the functions of the pair elements can be called, etc. Is there a way to explicitly hide all the base functions and members, or is there a way to support the aggregate initialization without having public base types and not giving up the empty base class optimization or the trivial constructibility if A and B are trivially constructible?

Comment: Why not change PairElement to privately inherit from T, provide a protected accessor in PairElement which returns the reference to T, and call that from first()?

Comment: That would break the aggregate initialization, so then I would need a constructor which would disallow trivial constructibility.

Comment: That would still be an aggregate, right? Granted if T has a constructor you'd still need a constructor, but you can inherit T's: https://godbolt.org/z/dCVqd7